# Cannot find module in import path error

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, libpng

I have some of my own C++ code compiling and running fine using the NDK. As I can't see any way to access the libpng library that is built into Android,  my only option seems to be  to compile my own version and use that (I'd be interested to know about alternatives).

I'm currently trying to extend my code to make use of libpng. I can't work out how to get my code to build. I've read the docs and scoured through newsgroup question and answers but I can't resolve my problem.

I've copied libpng to my source tree. I'm trying to compile libpng as a static library and then have my code use this to access libpng's functions. Here is what I have so far for my make files:

```
########## Directory layout ##########

jni/
  Android.mk
  mylib/
    Android.mk
    source files...
  libpng/
    Android.mk
    source files...

########## Top-level Android.mk ##########

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/mylib/Android.mk

########## mylib Android.mk ##########

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libpng
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_CFLAGS := 

sources := mylib.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(sources:%=mylib/%)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module, libpng)

########## libpng Android.mk ##########

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := 
LOCAL_MODULE := libpng

sources :=\
    png.c \ # etc.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(sources:%=libpng/%)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

---

mylib is my code that already compiles if I remove all the libpng material. libpng will compile successfully on its own as well. Notice I'm keeping my code and the libpng code in separate directories and trying to use a top-level make file to compile these.

The current error message that I'm stuck on when attempting to build mylib is:

Cannot find module with tag 'libpng' in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?

I've set NDK_MODULE_PATH to $(LOCAL_PATH) which I believe means the build process should find libpng/Android.mk but it doesn't. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `LOCAL_MODULE := png` instead of `libpng`